# How do very small capacitors have large capacitance values?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

I was trying to make my own capacitor and found it hard to make it even equal to $1\mu F$ of capacitance.

$ C= \epsilon A/d$

What i can do to have large capacitance is to have large $\epsilon $ value and large Area of metal plate and very thin gap between them. I was thinking of how to bring capacitance to about $ 10\mu F$ or $100\mu F$ but didn't have any idea of how to do this without using area of $1m^2$ or more.

Then i found a axial capacitance from a circuit. It was very small it had area of metal plate less than $10cm^2$. It was rated 10V and 68$\mu F$.

How was that capacitor able to have such capacitance?

Answer (score 1):

Electrolytic capacitors have high capacitance because between anode and cathode there is a very thin layer of oxyde which can be about 1nm. If you are interested in obtaining even greater capacitances (eg 1000F) you can search about super-capacitors, but they use a different technology.

Comment: A second method used to increase the capacitance is to increase the area of the electrode, even though the linear dimensions are small. In the case of tantalum capacitors the the material on which the oxide layer is formed is porous, for aluminium ons the surface is structured/rough.

Comment: But the capacitor I am talking about had a paper like dielectric or insulation. So the case here is quitely different.

Answer (score 1):

Older capacitors had thin sheets of foil separated by thin sheets of a paper-like insulator. These started as long narrow strips, but were then rolled to form cylinders. The rolling allowed the electric field to go in both directions from each metal strip, thus doubling the capacitance.  I have read that some modern capacitors start as a highly porous piece of metal. The pores are filled with a liquid that coats the inner surfaces with an insulating film. Then that liquid is removed and replaced with one that introduces a conductor.

Comment: So i should multiply the Capacitance i found with 2 if the metal sheets are rolled. Does increasing thickness of sheet affects it?

Comment: Thicker sheets might be more difficult to roll, and would  increase the final volume.

Comment: ... but thinner sheets mean higher internal resistance (usually quantified as equvalent series resistance). (Although typically still less than for an electrolytic capacitor).